# Is it possible to configure (not point!) subdomains & mx records somewhere other than with the registrar?

Tags: dns, domain-registrar

I've run into some trouble with a recently launched site disrupting other subdomains and mail servers. The domain name is registered with Network Solutions, and they've told me that there were never any mx records or subdomains setup in their DNS records. Is it possible that they were somehow setup with another registrar, even though Network Solutions held the domain name?

The questions everyone seems to think I'm asking is whether or not you can host a subdomain somewhere other than with the registrar... of course you can! I need to know if someone could have set these records up with another registrar so I can find them and put everything back as it should be :-).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you not fairly familiar with DNS, and followed your web hosts directions with success, then it is quite possible that you set it all up at the web host. I recommend against it of course because people often get confused. Case in point. NetSol should be able to tell you more. For example, they should be telling you if you have a web hosts name servers set up. I would begin there. I would also call your web host.

Comment: Yes it is possible.  All of the following can be handled different companies:  Domain name registration, DNS hosting, email hosting, website hosting, subdomain website hosting.

Comment: Yes. People can set up sub-domains off of your parent domain by simply defining them in their own DNS. This is fairly rare though. Can you be more specific in what trouble you are having so that we can narrowly answer your question. Otherwise, this question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registrar carries the domain name and it is there where you can tell them where the nameserver(s) are. You cannot have a domain name that is not registered at one registrar point to nameservers not registered with it. It is a registrars main job to do this correctly.

Since you can't point the main domain with any other registrar, you can't point subdomains either.

To possibly help clear things up, you should look into tools for discovery like nslookup, dig, drill, and following information from there with whois.

There are more tools but let's see how far that gets you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can handle it.

Want free solution? Use [Cloudflare DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/dns/).

Want premium solution? Go with [Google Cloud DNS](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/) or [Amazon route53](https://aws.amazon.com/route53/) or [easydns](https://www.easydns.com/). Lot's of choices are available.

With most of them you just need to point your name server.

Comment: It appears that the OP is actually asking something other than what it appears. Sorry. Asked for clarification.

Comment: I did not say more, because stephen already said in comments. He is absolutely right. So I just give him option to where to go for more information.

Comment: The OP was not being clear. In fact, for me the question is still not clear.